# ui-grid Data display issue

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid with my Cordova application. When I try to populate the ui-grid, sometimes data is displayed on the left like in the picture below:

[image]

Any help?

**HTML**

```
<div ui-grid="{data: gridOptions, columnDefs: gridColumns, paginationPageSize: 10, enableColumnMenus: false, enableHorizontalScrollbar : 0,
                enableVerticalScrollbar : 0}" ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pagination class="grid_transmiss"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.gridColumns = [{
        field: 'ref',
        displayName: 'Référence'
      }, {
        field: 'Emq',
        displayName: 'Nombre de plots empilés'
      }, {
        field: 'charge',
        displayName: 'Charge nominale (daN)'

      }, {
        field: 'fp',
        displayName: 'Fréquence propre(Hz)'
      }, {
        field: 'attenuation',
        displayName: 'Atténuation(%)'
      }, {
        field: 'flechereel',
        displayName: 'Flèche réelle statique (mm)'
      }, {
        name: 'Courbe',
        displayName: 'Courbe',
        cellTemplate: '<i ng-click="grid.appScope.goToChart()"><img src="img/chart.png" style="width=20px;height:20px" alt="Voir courbe" /></i>'
      }];
```

Comment: what does your columnDefs in your gridOptions look like?

Comment: you can see details above

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your grid in your controller like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'ref', displayName: 'Référence', width: "*"
        },
      {
          field: 'Emq', displayName: 'Nombre de plots empilés', width: "*"
      },
      {
          field: 'charge', width: 110, displayName: 'Charge nominale (daN)'
      },
      {    field: 'fp', displayName: 'Fréquence propre(Hz)', width: "*" 
      },
      {
          field: 'attenuation', displayName: 'Atténuation(%)', width: "*"

      },
      {
          field: 'flechereel', displayName: 'Flèche réelle statique (mm', width: "*"


      },
      {
          field: 'Courbe', displayName: 'Release Courbe', width: "*",
          cellTemplate: '<i ng-click="grid.appScope.goToChart()"><img src="img/chart.png" style="width=20px;height:20px" alt="Voir courbe" /></i>'
      },
        ],
        showGridFooter: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        paginationPageSizes: [100, 120, 140],
        paginationPageSize: 100,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
        enableGridMenu: false,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

        }
};
```

Then in your HTML:

```
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
```

Also, make sure you include 'uiGridConstants' in our controller definition like so:

```
    ContractorCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', '$window', '$filter', 'uiGridConstants', '$q', '$timeout'];
function ContractorCtrl($scope, $interval, $window, $filter, uiGridConstants, $q, $timeout)
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

change your column definition according to below format. It will work.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                    columnDefs: [
                        {name:'clumnName', fields: 'DisplayValue', width: '20%'},
                        {name:'clumnName', fields: 'DisplayValue', width: '20%'},
                        {name:'clumnName', fields: 'DisplayValue', width: '20%'},

                    ],


                    data: $scope.DisplayDataSet,
                }
```